# why is this javascript not working in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

Can anybody tell me why the javascript for the gallery on the page below is fine in Firefox, but isn't working properly in Chrome and Safari?

http://luxe-deluxe.com/collections/winter2011.html

In Chrome, the big image doesn't show up but the thumbnails do, and in Safari nothing shows up.

'Don't think it could have anything to do with the css... could it?

any help is appreciated... I'll post the answer if I find it. arg!

Comment: An un-minified version of the javascript is going to be necessary to help here...

Comment: Just clear your browser cache and try again?

Comment: when you copy the url of the image which isn't working it's actually the link of the page...

Comment: firefox console is showing this error: Image corrupt or truncated: http://yoursite/.....jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
document.images.src = img[imgNumber];
```

isn't working. It should be

```
document.getElementById('images').src = img[imgNumber];
```

Same with the line

```
document.images.src = img[this.id];
```

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('images').src = img[this.id];
```

Once those were fixed, the slideshow worked for me in a local copy.

Comment: Thanks heaps for all the feedback, you guys rock! g_thom your answer was particularily concise and to the point; exactly what a beginner like myself needed. Now I should look up what 'minified' and 'error console' actually are/do.

Comment: maybe I should have written 'chrome, safari and IE' in my question... just realized it doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting `<img src="" id="images">` with no source.
Try to alert `alert(document.images.src);` == undefined.

Try `document.getElementById("images").src` instead.

```
var NumberOfImages = 9

var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

img[0] = "Susielookbook-561.jpg"
img[1] = "Luxe Deluxe W11 (9).jpg"
img[2] = "Luxe Deluxe W11 (10).jpg"
img[3] = "Luxe Deluxe W11 (13).jpg"
img[4] = "Luxe Deluxe W11 (19).jpg"
img[5] = "Susielookbook-259.jpg"
img[6] = "Susielookbook-293.jpg"
img[7] = "Susielookbook-431.jpg"
img[8] = "Susielookbook-613.jpg"

var imgNumber = 0;
function setupImages(){
    document.images.src = img[imgNumber];
    for(var x=0; x < img.length; x++){

        var thumb = document.createElement('img');
        thumb.setAttribute('src', 't_'+img[x]);
        thumb.id = x;
        thumb.onclick = function(){
            document.images.src = img[this.id];
            imgNumber = this.id;
            alert(document.images.src);                  // <-- here
        }
        document.getElementById('thumbnailholder').appendChild(thumb);
    }
}   

function NextImage() {
    imgNumber++;
    if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages){
        imgNumber = 0;
    } 
    document.images.src = img[imgNumber];
}

function PreviousImage() {
    imgNumber--;
    if (imgNumber < 0){
        imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1;
    }  
    document.images.src = img[imgNumber];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, oliholz! I'm afraid I have a lot of work to do in js because I wasn't able to implement your solution. i couldn't find the line  alert(document.images.src);  in my code, so I put in your new line  where you indicated... but to no avail. I'll keep at it!